# Applying a Global Variable to a $.getjson request URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get, global-variables

So I'm having trouble getting my getJSON request to pass a global variable for address into the URL. I've included below the google method for acquiring said address through it's API which I then set to the global variable = globalStringAddress. This function occurs after the user is prompted to agree to location sharing.

```
var map, infowindow, globalStringAddress




    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 38.907, lng: -77.036},
        zoom: 10
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

    //   // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };
          console.log(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude); 
          //  console.log(poslat + ", " + poslng);
           var latlng = {lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng};
           geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[0]) {
            map.setZoom(11);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
            });
            globalStringAddress = results[0].formatted_address
            console.log("address is : "+ globalStringAddress);
            infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            var globalStringAddress = globalStringAddress.replace(/[\s]/g, '+').replace(/[,]/g, '%2C');    
            //var civicAPI ="https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address="+globalStringAddress+"&key=AIzaSyBwA2-va1J2oaO3IhPn2xqItnyUyhkfkqk";
            console.log(globalStringAddress);




          } else {
            window.alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });



          infowindow.setPosition(pos);
          infowindow.setContent('Cool House Loser');
          infowindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
          handleLocationError(true, infowindow, map.getCenter());
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infowindow, map.getCenter());
      }
      console.log("address is : "+ globalStringAddress)
    }
    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
    }
```

the problem occurs here at the getJSON request. I can't get the globalStringAddress variable to pass into the URL in a manner that would allow it's execution. I should probably mention I've done some editing of it inside of the initMap function in an attempt to make it more url friendly but the result is constantly https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address=[object%20Object]&key=xxx.

```
$(document).ready(function(globalStringAddress) {
  $("#officials").click(function(globalStringAddress){
      $.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address="+globalStringAddress+"&key=xxx", function(result){

        window.localStorage.setItem('Senator1', result.officials[2].name),
        window.localStorage.setItem('Senator2', result.officials[3].name),
        Senator1= result.officials[2].name,
        Senator2= result.officials[3].name,
        $("#lobby").append(
        "You're Senators are " + result.officials[2].name + " & " + result.officials[3].name,
        " and you're Representative is " + result.officials[4].name),
       // console.log(result.officials[3].channels[0].id),
        $.each(result.officials , function(k , v){
          $("#lobby").append(
            //  v.name +' - '+ v.address[0].line1 + " and ",

        );
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Is this a positioning issue? Should I declare globalStringAddress as a string? Is this a synchronization issue ? Any arrow in the right direction is much appreciated as I'm somewhat new to modulation

Comment: When you use `function(globalStringAddress)` the `globalStringAddress` will defined again with index or object .. So remove `globalStringAddress` from `function(globalStringAddress)` ready and click function

Comment: This makes it undefined within the URL (https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address=undefined&key=xxx) passing it through both of those functions was the only way I got any semblance of content in the globalStringAddress postion

Comment: could it be undefined because on the page load globalStringAddress is undefined until initMap is executed? Again my experience with modulation is really just beginning but I am getting correct address details logged to the console within initMap

Comment: you can start from `undefined` that mean your variable is still not updated within the other functions

Comment: so the problem is with the structure of the initMap function? should I have that be the first thing that the page does so that in lower functions it will be identified?

Comment: the simple way .. in click event  wrap the `getJSON` in `if (typeof globalStringAddress  !== 'undefined'){  //getjson here  }`

Comment: this is making the button itself unresponsive

Comment: Yes it will response when the `globalStringAddress` is defined to make sure the click will happen when `globalStringAddress` gets defined .. then you can search your code why its still undefined .. this is just for check not a solution

Comment: I gotcha. realizing that now. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?address=" + JSON.stringify(globalStringAddress) + "&key=xxx", function(result) {...});
```

Comment: nah that's making it error out with Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.html:219)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)

Comment: sorry that's wonky btw. not sure how to reformat these comments

Answer (score 0):

So I got this to work by nesting the lower jQuery into the initMap() function. I think the problem is with my lack luster method of declaring the globalStringAddress variable global from within the function? idk but it's populating into the URL just fine now